# How to use subquery based on range?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have 2 tables: Person and Category. To simplify the problem i need to join both tables based on the age range. I need to show every person with the corresponding age title. I thought was easy but get an error with the order by inside the subquery.

Table PERSON:

```
NAME    AGE
Laura   16
Peter   3
Juan    24
Tomas   31
```

Table CATEGORY:

```
YEAR  TITLE
0     Baby
5     Kid
11    Teenager
18    Young
33    Adult
65    Old Age
```

Result query:

```
Name    Age     Title
Laura   16      Teenager
Peter   3       Baby
Juan    24      Young
Tomas   31      Young
```

How can I achive the result query?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show the code / query and the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the analytic function `LEAD` to create a year range, and then join on that range.  Joining on ranges is often slow but it shouldn't matter for such a small number of rows.  (If the PERSON table is large there is probably a way to make this join more efficient, but it would also make the code more complicated.)

```
select person.name, person.age, ranges.title
from person
join
(
    select
        title,
        year min_age,
        nvl(lead(year) over (order by year), 99999999) max_age
    from category
) ranges
    on person.age between ranges.min_age and ranges.max_age
order by name;

NAME    AGE   TITLE
----    ---   -----
Juan     24   Young
Laura    16   Teenager
Peter     3   Baby
Tomas    31   Young
```

Based on these tables:

```
create table person as
select 'Laura' name, 16 age from dual union all
select 'Peter' name, 3  age from dual union all
select 'Juan'  name, 24 age from dual union all
select 'Tomas' name, 31 age from dual;

create table category as
select 0  year, 'Baby'     title from dual union all
select 5  year, 'Kid'      title from dual union all
select 11 year, 'Teenager' title from dual union all
select 18 year, 'Young'    title from dual union all
select 33 year, 'Adult'    title from dual union all
select 65 year, 'Old Age'  title from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

A canonical method is a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (select c.title
        from category c
        where c.year <= p.age
        order by c.year desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as title
from person p;
```

This can also be expressed as a lateral join:

```
select p.*, c.title
from person p left join lateral
     (select c.title
      from category c
      where c.year <= p.age
      order by c.year desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) c on 1=1;
```